# How to properly manage memory and batch size with TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, tensorflow, keras

I am using TensorFlow to build a simple feed-forward neural network, and I am using variable size batches. I am not using the GPU, I have 8GB RAM, and running on Python 3.5.2.

My problem is that I have some batches that are too big and are generating the typical out of memory error. I understand that, it is not a problem. However, if I use Keras with TF backend I don't have that issue. I have built an example (with fixed size batches) bellow that illustrates this.

Is there a problem with my implementation? How should I handle batches that are too big?

#### TensorFlow example (exhausts memory)

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

n_observations = 100000
n_input = 6
batch_size = 20000
X = np.random.rand(n_observations, n_input)
Y = X[:,0] ** 3 + X[:,1] ** 2 + X[:,2] + X[:,3] + X[:,4] + X[:,5]+ np.random.rand(n_observations)

n_hidden = 16
n_output = 1

def generatebatch(n_observations, batch_size):
    for batch_i in range(n_observations // batch_size):
        start = batch_i*batch_size
        end = start + batch_size
        batch_xs = X[start:end, :]
        batch_ys = Y[start:end]
        yield batch_xs, batch_ys

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # placeholders for input and target
    net_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
    y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    # Hidden Layer
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden]))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden]))
    net_output1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(net_input, W1) + b1)

    # Yet another Hidden Layer
    yaW1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_hidden]))
    yab1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden]))
    yanet_output1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(net_output1, yaW1) + yab1)

    # Output Layer
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_output]))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]))
    net_output2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(yanet_output1, W2) + b2)

    # The loss function
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_true - net_output2, 2))

    # Configure the optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    # Initialize variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    n_epochs = 100
    for epoch_i in range(n_epochs):
        batchloss = []
        for batch_xs, batch_ys in generatebatch(n_observations, batch_size):
            _, loss = sess.run(
                [optimizer, cost],
                feed_dict={
                    net_input: batch_xs,
                    y_true: batch_ys
            })
            batchloss.append(loss)
        print(np.mean(batchloss))
```

#### Keras Example (handles the batch size somehow)

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import logging

#just to hide the deprecation warnings
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)

n_input = 6
n_observations = 100000
n_hidden = 16
n_epochs = 10
batch_size = 35000

# input data
X = np.random.rand(n_observations, n_input)
Y = X[:,0] ** 3 + X[:,1] ** 2 + X[:,2] + X[:,3] + X[:,4] + X[:,5]+ np.random.rand(n_observations)

# create and fit Multilayer Perceptron model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_hidden, input_dim=n_input, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_hidden, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Y` has incorrect shape, maybe causing tensorflow to infer shape of tensors incorrectly ((20000, 20000) instead of (20000, 6), for example), consuming a lot of memory.

```
Y = np.reshape(Y, [n_observations, 1])
```

Thus your placeholder should have the SAME shape:

```
net_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_input])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. Can you elaborate a bit more on "maybe coursing tensorflow do a lot of reshapings and memory leaks."?  Y and y_true had the same [wrong] shape before (n_observations,). Why do we have to do it like this?

Comment: sorry, a second thought gave me another more likely 'maybe': tensorflow tries to infer shape of intermediate tensors at `sess.run`, from the shape of `feed_dict` values. A wrong `X`, `Y` and placeholder setup could cause some inner tensor's shape to be inferred as (20000, 20000) instead of (20000, 6), consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Keras is overriding the default configuration options in TensorFlow. Your native TensorFlow code runs fine with smaller batch sizes (e.g. 10k, 15k) on the GPU.  But with the default configuration, it is going to assume you want GPU benefits and the OOM issue happens because there is not enough GPU memory.

Your TensorFlow example works fine when you do change that default behavior to CPU (as you indicated in the question).  Here are the lines I changed to do that:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(
    log_device_placement=True, allow_soft_placement=True
)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True


with tf.Session(config=config) as sess, \
        tf.device('cpu:0'):  # placeholders for input and target
```

Comment: I've tried this but I get a message `Device mapping: no known devices`. I tried other methods to force CPU only but I still get OOM : `W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[20000,20000]
  [[Node: gradients/Pow_grad/Select = Select[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients/Pow_grad/Greater, gradients/Pow_grad/Log, gradients/Pow_grad/zeros_like)]]
`